# should we use 1 cluster on divide into clusters

Tags: kubernetes

we have a kubernetes cluster that holds all our components on version 1.9.2.
the cluster includes streaming components and NOSQL data-base components plus a few more smaller editions.

we need to integrate with a different group which will rely deeply on our platform/streaming/databases and all our kubernetes cluster.

I was wondering what is the proper approach for that?
should the components of the second group reside on the same cluster as those streaming/data-base components?

what will be the meaning if we decide to split into 2 different clusters?
assuming those the other group components will have to interact the the streaming/data-base components heavily , will it affect performmnace if they reside on a different cluster opposed to running on the same cluster?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Namespaces. Having multiple clusters can increase costs and complicate logistics (security, installation, updates, monitoring). For an HA cluster close to 5 nodes (2 masters, 3 etcd) are needed for the control plane of Kubernetes. It's often more cost effective to scale up more nodes on your existing cluster. Isolation can be achieved with [kind: Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/#when-to-use-multiple-namespaces) and you may want to consider [kind: NetworkPolicy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/). [Istio Mesh can also help with isolation](https://istio.io/blog/2018/soft-multitenancy/).

Another consideration is cost and cluster administration. If you are using any other provider than GKE, each master will cost you on a monthly basis. Different clusters will also require their independent cluster roles, which can be a double-edged sword.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am not saying cost is not an issue but I want to address the performance/security/management overhead. are there any performance issues?

Comment: There should not be added performance costs. You are simply adding a few more nodes to the existing cluster. K8s is designed to scale like this. You may even find you don't need to add more nodes if you are already over allocated in the existing cluster. The bin packing algorithm in the scheduler takes care of finding resources on nodes where it can run your containers. You will be adding less nodes by adding to the existing cluster. Given a very large increase in node cluster you may have to increase the number of masters and etcd, but that's typically not something most of us will hit.

Comment: I am not talking about adding more nodes. I am talking about performance regarding running services that are talking to one another on the same cluster opposed to using different clusters completely